# how to deploy web app to jetty

Tags: selenium-rc, maven-jetty-plugin

I have an web app(actually a gwt app), and i want to deploy it to Jetty server for selenium testing, i used maven, maven-jetty-plugin, gwt-maven-plugin and selenium-maven-plugin, i finally got jetty and selenium sever running but the selenium tests fail because of the famous 404 eror:

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: XHR ERROR: URL = http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html Response_Code = 404 Error_Message = Not Found
```

i m not sure if my jetty configuration is correct since i m kind of new to it, here is it(maven-jetty-plugin):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>

  <configuration>
    <contextPath>/sample-console</contextPath>
    <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</webAppSourceDirectory>
    <webXml>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
  </configuration>
          <executions>
             <execution>
                <id>start-jetty</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                 <configuration>
                    <daemon>true</daemon>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
             <execution>
                <id>stop-jetty</id>
                <phase>post-integraion-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>stop</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions> 
</plugin>
```

when i ran mvn clean install, i can see the output from command window:

```
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: DYI sample Console
[INFO] Webapp source directory = /Users/dyi/Documents/workspace/sample/console/target/sample-console-0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = /Users/dyi/Documents/workspace/sample/console/target/classes
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.mortbay.log).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[INFO] Context path = /sample-console
[INFO] Tmp directory =  determined at runtime
[INFO] Web defaults = org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = /Users/dyi/Documents/workspace/sample/console/target/sample-console-0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = /Users/dyi/Documents/workspace/sample/console/target/sample-console-0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Starting jetty 6.1.22 ...
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
[INFO] [selenium:start-server {execution: start}]
```

and my folder structure looks like this:

```
--sample/
   -- console/
        -- src/
        -- target/
             -- classes/
             -- sample-console-0.1-SNAPSHOT/
                   -- css/
                   -- images/
                   -- img/
                   -- index.html
                   -- js/
                   -- META-INF/
                   -- security/
                   -- test.html
                   -- WEB-INF/ 
                         -- classes/
                         -- lib/
                         -- web.xml
```

the thing i don't understand is i can see the index.html page is right there in the folder 'sample-console-0.1-SNAPSHOT', why it cannot find it? is that because i set the 'contextPath' wrong? i tried setting it to '/', then i got 503 service not available error. anyone can help? much thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to run the app out of the webapp directory, which won't work in a GWT app.  Try setting the goal in your jetty maven plugin to be run-war instead of run, like this:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.proj.web</groupId>
<artifactId>gwtapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>gwtapp</name>

<properties>
    ...
</properties>
<dependencies>
    ...
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/integration/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-tests</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>none</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/integration/**
                    </include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Selenium and integration testing support -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>                
                <execution>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start-server</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <background>true</background>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop-server</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>   
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.2.v20101205</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
                </webAppConfig>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>9080</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run-war</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-1</version>
            <configuration>
                <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
                <style>PRETTY</style>
                <runTarget>/gwtapp.html</runTarget>
                <hostedWebapp>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</hostedWebapp>
                <modules>
                    <module>${project.groupId}.gwtapp</module>
                </modules>
                <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>gwtcompile</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
</build>
```

This will cause the compile and gwt-compile to run., assuming you have those configured correctly.

If your config looks like this, you can just run `mvn clean integration-tests` and your script will:

1. Compile your code
2. gwt:compile your code
3. Create the war file
4. start jetty and deploy the war file to jetty
5. Start the Selenium server
6. try to run any tests in any subdirectory of the integration package in your test directory.